# Spring injected bean thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, dependency-injection, thread-safety

I am having a kind of 'Task' class that contains a spring injected bean. ( will set via setter method)

this Task class will be initiated as a new object and will pass in to the `theradpool`.

so every task class has that injected bean in it.

when i use a method in that bean class will it be thread safe? ( since the bean is a `singleton`)

also please note that there are no class level variables defined in that bean class.

Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stateless object is always inherently thread-safe. Since it uses only local variables, there is no way for one thread to corrupt the state used by another concurrent thread.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so that means even though it uses single instance it will be thread safe right? so injected bean object will reside on the heap of the memory and for every thread will have there own method stacks for that object is it?

Comment: @JBNizet : But if we modify injected bean(which is singleton), changes will be reflected in all other threads...right? :)

Comment: There is no way to change anything in this singleton, since it's stateless. How would you change the state of something which doesn't have state?

Answer (score 0):

whether your solution is really thread-safe depends on great many details that you haven't provided, but one item that is obvious from your problem statement is the question of thread-safety of the injected bean. The singleton itself might not be thread-safe.

Comment: you mean if the singleton have class variables and if it is injected to many 'Task' classes ( meaning that same object reference will injected to the multiple 'Task' Classes.) it will not be thread safe. is it? ( lets say singleton have a class variable called Logger , and it is initiated inside the singleton constructor)

Comment: It has nothing directly to do with class variables, but with the **sharing of state between threads**. If you share your singleton between threads, this is practically the same thing as if that singleton was stored in a class variable. Same for the variables in the singleton itself. My point is that you must be sure that your singleton object is designed to be thread-safe. For example, if that object were an instance of `DateFormat`, it would **not** be thread-safe.